# Custom Zend Validator

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

I want to create a custom validator in Zend.

for e.g. my code:

```
$txt_state = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('state');
$txt_state->setLabel('State');

$txt_prop = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('pin');
$txt_prop->setLabel('Property');
```

Now I want that the form must be submitted only if at least one of these 2 elements are not empty.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it dirty way like this:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if (is_empty($form->getElement('state')->getValue())) {
        $form->getElement('pin')->setRequired();
    }
    if (is_empty($form->getElement('pin')->getValue())) {
        $form->getElement('state')->setRequired();
    }

   if ($form->isValid()) {
     //redirect to success page 
   } else {
    //do nothing, display errors messages, refill form 
   }
}
```

or cleaner with extended Zend_Form_Element.

Comment: What is this? I want the default behavior of Zend i.e. if a validation fails, the control returns to form page again with the error message.

Comment: Then additionaly add this code:

if ($form->isValid()) {
    //redirect to success page
} else {
   //do nothing, display errors messages, refill form
}

Answer (score 0):

Here you can add custom validation like this in controller.

```
$state = "YOUR VALUE";

$form->state->setValue($state);
$form->getElement('state')->setRequired();
$form->getElement('state')->addValidator( 'Alpha', true, array( 'messages' => array( 'notAlpha' => "Please enter alphabetic character only in state name.
") ));

$mArr = array('state'=>$state);

if( !$form->isValid($mArr) ){

    $myErrorArray[] = $form->getMessages();

    $is_error = 1;
}
```

Here **$myErrorArray** have all error message that you apply on element state.